# MongoDB Atlas Device Sync (App Services) - React Native

Tags: javascript, mongodb, react-native, realm, atlas-device-sync

i am building a react-native-app with MongoDB - App Services as backend.

Everything worked fine already, until i added a custom schema object type (User_location). The SDK don't want to accept it.

Here is my schema-model for a User:

```
import "react-native-get-random-values";
import Realm, { BSON, ObjectSchema } from "realm";
// import { User_location } from "./User_location";

export class User extends Realm.Object<User> {
  _id!: BSON.ObjectId;
  userName?: string;
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  email!: string;
  avatar?: string;
  userId!: string;
  admin!: boolean;
  location?: User_location;

  static schema: ObjectSchema = {
    name: "User",
    primaryKey: "_id",
    properties: {
      _id: { type: "objectId", default: () => new BSON.ObjectId() },
      userName: "string?",
      firstName: "string?",
      lastName: "string?",
      email: "string",
      avatar: "string?",
      userId: "string",
      admin: "bool",
      location: "User_location?",
    },
  };
}

export class User_location extends Realm.Object {
  latitude!: number;
  longitude!: number;

  static schema: ObjectSchema = {
    name: "User_location",
    embedded: true,
    properties: {
      latitude: "double",
      longitude: "double",
    },
  };
}
```

The error i get:

> [Error: Object type 'User_Location' not found in schema.]

I followed exactly the example in the docs here:
[https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/model-data/relationships-and-embedded-objects/]

I defined a class for the ObjectType and used it as a SchemaType, as shown in the docs, but it still doesn't know the type. What did i miss here?

Comment: The error references `User_Location` (capital L) not `User_location` lower case L, so that error may be caused by some other code, or the object was possibly renamed at some point so it exists on the server but not locally.

Comment: Thank you @Jay, that was a helpful hint. It seems, that it is not allowed to use that lowercase after lowdash naming (in opposite to documentation), because i changed the naming of the type to "Userlocation" instead of "User_location" and now it works.